# Prove or disprove : Every bounded sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that all convergent sequences are bounded. I also know that the converse is not true in general and a counter example would be $\{1,-1,1,-1, \ldots\}$

How do I properly disprove this?

Comment: You just did. One counter-example is sufficient.

Comment: Do I need to provide any explanation or anything? Or is that sufficient enough

Comment: The only step left is to prove that the sequence $1,-1,1,-1\dots$ does not converge, then you are done.

Comment: Note however that every bounded sequence in $\Bbb R$ [has a converging subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: A counter-example is enough, you dont need to do something more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to say! In a civilized society, you can just write "The sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ is a counterexample."

If you're worried that your grader wants more, you can also go through explicit proofs that it is bounded and not convergent. That shouldn't be necessary, but you can judge what they expect better than we can on the Internet.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ and suppose that $(a_n)$ converges to $a$. Then:

$a_{n+1}-a_n \to a-a=0$ and therefore $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \to 0$.

But we have  $|a_{n+1}-a_n| =2$ for all $n$, a contradiction.